# PHP Regexp (PCRE) - Find a set of all substrings 2

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

For example have a source string:

```
__aaXXccYYeeXX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ZZvv..
```

How can I find all: aaXX*YY*ZZ

__ **aaXX** cc **YY** eeXX_ **ZZ** kkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ZZvv..

__ **aaXX** cc **YY** eeXX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ **ZZ** nnXXooYYuuXX_ZZvv..

__ **aaXX** cc **YY** eeXX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ **ZZ** vv..

__ **aaXX** ccYYeeXX_ZZkk **YY** mmXX_ **ZZ** nnXXooYYuuXX_ZZvv..

__ **aaXX** ccYYeeXX_ZZkk **YY** mmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ **ZZ** vv..

__ **aaXX** ccYYeeXX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXoo **YY** uuXX_ **ZZ** vv..

The problem is that a PHP preg doesn't support ?+* (variable length) in (?<=exp) lookbehind assertion (allow only with fixed length {N}).

So need solution without using lookbehind assertion with variable length.

Thank you!

Comment: Documentation I'm reading says PHP does indeed support lookbehind. Please post your code.

Comment: @Cfreak - it supports look-behind, but not variable length. You can look for "foo" before your pattern, but not for [a-z]{2,3}; @Dmitrij, but why do you need lookbehind in this case?

Comment: Exactly.
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script works:

```php
<?php // test.php 20110311_1200
    $data = '__aaXXccYYeeXX_ZZkkYYmmXX_ZZnnXXooYYuuXX_ZZvv..';
    $all_matches = array();
    $yy_match = true; // Get past first for test condition.
    for ($yy_cnt = 1; $yy_match; ++$yy_cnt) {
        $yy_match = false; // Assume failure for this yy_cnt.
        $zz_match = true; // Get past first for test condition.
        for ($zz_cnt = 1; $zz_match; ++$zz_cnt) {
            $zz_match = false; // Assume failure for this zz_cnt.
            // Assemble new regex with new $yy_cnt and $zz_cnt.
            $re = "/ # Match all combinations of XX..YY..ZZ.
                (aaXX)                   # $1: Prefix X.
                (?:                      # Group to find YY[yy_cnt].
                  (?:(?!YY).)*           # Zero or more non-YY.
                  (YY)                   # $2: next YY.
                ){{$yy_cnt}}             # yy_cnt.
                (?:                      # Group to find ZZ[zz_cnt].
                  (?:(?!ZZ).)*           # Zero or more non-ZZ.
                  (ZZ)                   # $3 next ZZ.
                ){{$zz_cnt}}             # $zz_cnt.
                /x";
            if (preg_match($re, $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                $zz_match = true;
                $yy_match = true;
                $all_matches[] = $matches;
                printf("Match found. \$yy_cnt = %d, \$zz_cnt = %d\n",
                    $yy_cnt, $zz_cnt);
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($all_matches);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop. First look for `__aaXX` followed by the next `YY`, then `__aaXX` followed by the second `YY` etc. In regex land that means you first look for `__aaXX(.*?YY){1}`, then `__aaXX(.*?YY){2}` (can you see a loop variable in there?) and so on until the pattern fails. Same for the second part when you are looking for the `ZZ`s.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Loop outside regex expression, you mean in PHP?

Comment: @Dmitrij: Yes, a regex can't grab them all in one go.

Comment: bobbogo is correct. See my answer for a tested script which implements the necessary loops. (Outside loop is YY, inside loop is ZZ)

Answer (score 0):

How about this pattern: `# aaXX(.*) YY (.*) ZZ .*#`?

From your highlighting it's not entirely clear what your result should look like... I added spaces because you have them in the highlighting, but it's not clear if you'll have them in your source...

**Edit**

I guess I'm not understanding what you want to get, but another thing to look at is preg_match_all, if your YY ZZ part repeats... Something like `#_aaXX((.*?)YY(.*?)ZZ)+#`.